# Is there a way to push Google Play Console reports to power BI?

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, google-play-console

I'm trying to consolidate my reports. Most of my reporting is through Power BI. I'm looking for a way to push google play console data on Downloads, store listing.... to power BI. There's no direct connector for Google Play console in Power BI so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in multiple ways.

- Using Google Search console API URL, noting that it has its limits, which are 2,000 queries per day, 600 queries per minute.
- Or you can Connect the google search console to BigQuery where your data will be stored and you'll have access to your historical data.
- Using a third-Party connector, that can help you connect Google Search Console to Power BI.

Comment: Thanks... I connected using Bigquery and it works. However on latest data is 3 days ago instead of D-1

Comment: I see, but maybe a third-party connector can help you with this.
Some have up to 1 hour.